# SSRS reporting using labels in expressions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, label, ssrs-expression

I am trying to produce a table - a count of responders by gender and site ID.

Instead of getting Site_ID out as 1, 2, 3 and Gender as 0, 1 on the graph I'm trying to recode Gender as Male / Female and Site_ID as Site 1, Site 2, Site 3, etc.

How can I set the expression for y, currently `=Count(Fields!GENDER.Value)` to put value labels (Male / Female) as outputs.

i.e. how can I put `=IIf(Fields!gender.Value = 1, "Male", "Female") into =Count(Fields!GENDER.Value)` for me to get the desired graph without errors?

Also the same for Site_ID where the expression for x is currently `=Fields!SID.Value` - how can I add value labels to this expression in `SSRS`?

My SQL skills are very rusty as you might have guessed (last used on an INGRES system years ago).

Thank you in advance for you time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like?

```
COUNT(IIF(Fields!gender.Value=1,"F",Nothing))
```

or

```
COUNT(IIF(Fields!gender.Value=1,"F","M"))
```